# Carry Stroller on Emirates flight without a kid?

Tags: luggage, international-travel, airlines, emirates

I am travelling from USA to India via Dubai in Emirates flight. I wanted to take a stroller for my sister in India that I bought in USA. Do I need to take it as part of my allowed check-in luggage? Or can that not be counted in allowed check in luggage? Also, since there is no child, so is it allowed to take it?

In worst case, I am thinking to put it inside one of my bag.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be allowed to take it, it's just regular luggage.  It'll probably be counted as part of your luggage allowance (since no infant booked)

Comment: It might be useful to add the folded size and weight of the item to the question.

Comment: Is it still in the original box? It might be easier to jut check it as a piece of luggage if so.  if not you could just carry it on as normal and then "gate check" it.

Comment: Maybe check the cost of checking it as baggage (piece of "oversized") compared to sending it in the post